# mysql wont connect to symlinked socket when given full path, but connects with relative

Tags: mysql, socket, symbolic-link, symlink

So I'm super confused.

I have a test build that started breaking because a mysql socket was attempting to be created in such a deeply nested folder that its file path name exceeded the 108 character limit.  So my thought was to put the socket in the test running users home directory in a similiarly named folder.  Ie:

`/home/nightlybuild/projects/......./myTestProject/output/db/connect.sock`
becomes
`/home/nightlybuild/myTestProject/output/db/connect.sock`

then I created a symlink in the nested dir:

`ln -s /home/nightlybuild/myTestProject/output/db/connect.sock /home/nightlybuild/projects/......./myTestProject/output/db/connect.sock`

Now heres what I'm confused about.  If I try to run mysql through that socket by passing ANY relative path to the socket in, I can connect and everything works as expected.  However, if I pass a full absolute path to the socket in, I get a can't connect error.

Works:
(from home dir):

`mysql --socket=projects/......./myTestProject/output/db/connect.sock`

(doesnt work):

`mysql --socket=/home/nightlybuild/projects/......./myTestProject/output/db/connect.sock`

I dont understand how the full path could be breaking it at all.  Anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong or even tips about a log or something I could look at to try and get more info about the problem?

Cheers!